# Pandas GroupBy and total sum within group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    interview       longitude        latitude
1   A1                  34.2             90.2
2   A1                  54.2             23.5
3   A3                  32.1             21.5
4   A4                  54.3             93.1
5   A2                  45.1             29.5
6   A1                  NaN              NaN
7   A7                  NaN              NaN
8   A1                  NaN              NaN
9   A3                  23.1             38.2
10  A5                  -23.7            -98.4
```

I would like to be able to perform some sort of groupby method that outputs me the total present values within each subgroup. So, desired output for something like this would be:

```
    interview         longitude         latitude       occurs 
1   A1                  2                2              4
2   A2                  1                1              1
3   A3                  2                2              2
4   A4                  1                1              1
5   A5                  1                1              1    
6   A7                  0                0              1
```

I tried to use this command to try with latitudes, but not getting the desired output:

```
df.groupby(by=['interview', 'latitude'])['interview'].count()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `notna` before `groupby` + `sum`

```
s1=(df[['**longitude**','**latitude**']].notna()).groupby(df['**interview**']).sum()
s2=df.groupby(df['**interview**']).size()# note size will count the NaN value as well 
pd.concat([s1,s2.to_frame('**occurs** ')],axis=1)
Out[115]: 
               **longitude**  **latitude**  **occurs** 
**interview**                                          
A1                       2.0           2.0            4
A2                       1.0           1.0            1
A3                       2.0           2.0            2
A4                       1.0           1.0            1
A5                       1.0           1.0            1
A7                       0.0           0.0            1
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use agg, simply pass the columns to groupby. Count returns count of not null values

```
df.groupby('interview')[['interview','longitude','latitude']].count()


        interview   longitude   latitude
interview           
A1      4           2           2
A2      1           1           1
A3      2           2           2
A4      1           1           1
A5      1           1           1
A7      1           0           0
```

Comment: I didn't know you could pass the columns you were grouping by to the groupby. That's pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

These three different ways how you can do it  :

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data = np.array([   
            ['A1',  'A1',   'A3'    ,'A4'   ,'A2'   ,'A1'   ,'A7',  'A1',   'A3',   'A5'],      
            [34.2,  54.2,   32.1,   54.3,   45.1,   np.NaN  ,np.NaN ,np.NaN,    23.1,   -23.7],
            [   90.2,   23.5,   21.5,   93.1,   29.5,       np.NaN,np.NaN   ,np.NaN ,38.2,  -98.4]])


    df = pd.DataFrame({'**interview**':data[0,:],'**longitude**':data[1,:],'**latitude**':data[2,:]})  

    #first way
    df['**occurs**']=1
    print(df.groupby('**interview**')[['**longitude**','**latitude**','**occurs**']].count().\
    reset_index())
    #or
     counts=0

gb = df.groupby(['**interview**'])
gb1 = df.groupby(['**interview**','**latitude**'])
counts = gb.size().to_frame(name='**occurs**')

print((counts
   .join(gb1.agg({'**longitude**':lambda x: x.notnull().size}))
 .join(gb1.agg({'**latitude**': lambda x: x.notnull().size}).rename(columns={'**latitude**': '*latitude*'}))

   .reset_index()
  ))

     #second way
    counts=0

    gb = df.groupby(['**interview**'])
    counts = gb.size().to_frame(name='**occurs**')

    print((counts
       .join(gb.agg({'**longitude**': 'size'}))
     .join(gb.agg({'**latitude**': 'size'}))

       .reset_index()
      ))

     #Third way   this just for compare
    print(df.groupby(['**interview**']).agg({'**longitude**':lambda x: x.notnull().sum(),
                                       '**latitude**':lambda x: x.notnull().sum(),
                                       '**interview**': 'size'})\
                                 .rename(columns={'**interview**':'**occurs**'}))
```

See the code here:https://repl.it/repls/OldVirtuousBooleanvalue